# Check if arrays inside another array have same element

Tags: php, arrays

It shouldn't be allowed same emails within array:

```
[
 ["first" => "John", "last" => "Snow","email" => "john@snow.com"],
 ["first" => "Sansa","last" => "Stark","email" => "sansa@stark.com"],
 ["first" => "Rob","last" => "Stark","email" => "john@snow.com"]
]
```

There can be unlimited number of elements of array type within outer array. Should I iterate with `foreach` and have some temp variable in which I am going to write `email` or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: What is the expected output and what are the different cases possible?

Comment: you want to remove first john or rob john?

Comment: I just want to display error that two same emails are in array

Comment: @AlivetoDie it is being created using javascript, and sent back to server, where I have to json decode it and then check for double values, and return true/false. That's why I can't do anything at the time of creation.

Comment: You need JS validation, but better to have it on server side as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple check that the count of the original array elements isn't equal to the count of the unique email addresses (done using `array_column()` and `array_unique()`).

```
if ( count($data) != count(array_unique(array_column($data, "email"))) )    {
    echo "Multiple";
}
```

(Assuming array is in `$data`).

Or for just true/false...

```
echo count($data) != count(array_unique(array_column($data, "email")));
```